# Google CSE open in new window

Tags: html, xhtml

I would like to integrate the Google Search bar into my site, and using the default code by Google CSE I have:

```
        <div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchOptions = {};

    var imageSearchOptions = {};
    imageSearchOptions['layout'] = google.search.ImageSearch.LAYOUT_POPUP;
    customSearchOptions['enableImageSearch'] = true;
    customSearchOptions['imageSearchOptions'] = imageSearchOptions;

    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(
      '003243520079760326318:WMX-1462312306', customSearchOptions);

    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');
    options.setAutoComplete(true);
    customSearchControl.draw('shop.htm/cse', options);
  }, true);
```

Followed by the style and the `</div>`

But I do not want the results to open on the same page, I want them to open in searchresults.htm which has the container div

```
<div id="cse" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

if I put in this form:

```
<form action="http://www.amberantiques.com/searchresults.htm" id="cse-search-box">
    <fieldset style="border:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="003243520079760326318:WMX-1462312306" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
        <input type="text" name="q" size="31" />
        <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then the form sends it to the page but doesnt run the search, but if you then use the Google bar on the page, it runs the search fine.

Basically, how do you get the google bar to open the results page?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're building the code for your Google CSE, one of the Look and Feel options is "Two Page" - which will allow you to search on one page, and display the results on another.
[image]

Answer (score 15):

If you upgrade to the latest Google Code V2 then you can achieve this by editing code you paste to show results.

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Change this to

```
<gcse:search linktarget="_parent"></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score 3):

The V2 code for the Custom Search (free) or Site Search (paid) gives you a range of options for searching and displaying results on the same page or having it's own result page.

By default this WILL open all result links in a new tab or window.

I had the issue where I needed the search results to open on the same tab/window.

I adjusted the following code

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

to this

```
<gcse:search linktarget="_self"></gcse:search>
```

I guess if for some reason your default behavior is not opening in a new tab/window and you need it to then you could try the following

```
<gcse:search linktarget="_blank"></gcse:search>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you test by putting this code?

```
options.enableSearchboxOnly("http://www.amberantiques.com/searchresults.htm");
```

between this line

```
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
```

and this line

```
options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');
```

Then put the following code in searchresults.htm

```
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parseQueryFromUrl() {
    var queryParamName = "q";
    var search = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var parts = search.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var keyvaluepair = parts[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[0]) == queryParamName) {
            return decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }
    }
    return '';
}

google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl(
  '003243520079760326318:WMX-1462312306', customSearchOptions);

    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
    var queryFromUrl = parseQueryFromUrl();
    if (queryFromUrl) {
        customSearchControl.execute(queryFromUrl);
    }
}, true);
</script>
```

If this doesn't work you can simply read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/dev_guide.html) provided by google. You'll get your desired information in [Designing the Look and Feel with the Control Panel](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/ui.html) section. Or you may find it in [Designing the Look and Feel with XML](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/ui_xml.html) section. I think you are looking for two page layout.

Another option is to go to http://www.google.com/cse/manage/all and then use the control panel there to customize your search engine as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the code above, you could use:

```
<gcse:search newWindow="true"></gcse:search>
```

According to [Google's documentation.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element)

Answer (score 0):

Not obvious from looking at the Google documentation (a familiar story) but you can do this very simply using the v2 Custom Search code by selecting the 'Results only' option in the 'Look and Feel' section:

[image: Look and feel selection screen with 'Results only' thumbnail selected]

Click 'Save and Get Code' and paste into your searchresults.htm page.

You now just need to create a simple search box that points to that page which you can put in your page header.

e.g.

```
<form action="http://www.amberantiques.com/searchresults.htm">
<input type="search" name="q"/>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```