# Google Custom Search Results - Link target blank does not go to new browser tab/window

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2005

I display the Google custom search results for my site onto a new page.  I would like the each search result, when clicked, to go to a new browser tab/window.

From my understanding of Google GCSE, clicking on a result should automatically go to a new browser window.  The Search Results linkTarget defaults to _blank.  I added the explicit code anyways.

```
<div class="searchresults-only" data-linkTarget="_blank"></div>
<gcse:searchresults-only linkTarget="_blank"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

What I see is that clicking on a search result stays in the same browser window and does not go to a new one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this may have your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461959/google-cse-open-in-new-window

Comment: As I recall, the link recommends the use of a gadget.  Gadgets to the best of my knowledge are for ASP.Net MVC web applications.  My web application is non-MVC, just plain ASP.Net, so that option appears to not be open to me.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="searchresults-only" data-linkTarget="_blank"></div>
```

Div code is not neccessary for this task
try this code

```
<gcse:searchresults-only linkTarget="_parent"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

it will help you.
just replace `linkTarget="_blank"` to `linkTarget="_parent"` and run it..